# Switching between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, join

I have two threads:

```
static Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Team1Shots));
static Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Team2Shots));
```

I want thread1 to do some work (but not complete), then thread2 to do some work (but not complete) and then to go back to finish thread1, then go back and finish thread2.

I have this so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    thread1.Start();
}

private static void Team1Shots()
{
   //Do Work in here...then

   thread2.Start();
   thread2.Join(); //Go to thread2

   //When join in thread2 to here
   //Do the rest of the work

   //Get thread2 to finish
}

private static void Team2Shots()
{
   //Do Work in here...
   thread1.Join(); //Go back to thread1

   //When thread1 finishes
   //Do the rest of the work

   // Finished All work
}
```

This is not working and do not know where to go from here.

Comment: You should be using semaphores or mutexes to synchronize multiple threads. `Thread.Join` doesn't do switching (it joins this thread to the existing one, blocking until it completes). You could also use a ManualResetEvent or critical sections (locks), there are a lot of options depending on what you need to do.

Comment: By the way, based on the comments, you've described an impossible situation. Thread1 starts thread 2, waits some time then thread 2 "switches" back to thread 1, does more work then waits on thread 2, but thread 2 is waiting on thread 1. The way its coded is a deadlock, the way its described is a live lock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you never actually want any of the work to be done in parallel, instead only ever having one of them doing work at a time, you should just not have two threads.  Have one thread that does all of the things that should be done first, then all of the things that should be done second, then all of the things that should be done next, and so on.  You're unnecessarily creating work by creating multiple threads that start/stop each other's progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`BlockingCollection(T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to communicate between threads. Model the steps as a state machine and you can ping-pong the messages between the threads.

```
// States
public enum MessageType
{
    Done,
    Work1,
    Work2,
    Work3,
    Work4
}

// Data
public class WorkerStateMessage
{
    public static readonly WorkerStateMessage Done =
        new WorkerStateMessage { Type = MessageType.Done };
    public MessageType Type { get; set; }
    public string Progress { get; set; }
    public int Data { get; set; }
}
```

Main

```
static Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Team1Shots));
static Thread thread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Team2Shots));
static BlockingCollection<WorkerStateMessage> thread1Messages =
    new BlockingCollection<WorkerStateMessage>();
static BlockingCollection<WorkerStateMessage> thread2Messages =
    new BlockingCollection<WorkerStateMessage>();
static BlockingCollection<WorkerStateMessage> progressMessages =
    new BlockingCollection<WorkerStateMessage>();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    thread1Messages.Add(new WorkerStateMessage { Type = MessageType.Work1, Data = 1 });
    thread1Messages.Add(new WorkerStateMessage { Type = MessageType.Work1, Data = 2 });
    thread1Messages.Add(new WorkerStateMessage { Type = MessageType.Work1, Data = 3 });
    thread1.Start();
    thread2.Start();
    // 4 step * 3 messages = 12 progress messages
    foreach(var message in progressMessages.GetConsumingEnumerable().Take(12))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message.Progress);
        Console.WriteLine("Current data: {0}", message.Data);
    }

    thread1Messages.Add(WorkerStateMessage.Done);
    thread2Messages.Add(WorkerStateMessage.Done);
    thread1.Join();
    thread2.Join();
}
```

Thread 1

```
private static void Team1Shots()
{
    foreach(var message in thread1Messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        WorkerStateMessage nextMessage;
        switch(message.Type)
        {
            case MessageType.Work1:
                var added = message.Data + 1;
                nextMessage = new WorkerStateMessage
                {
                    Type = MessageType.Work2, 
                    Progress = "Add 1",
                    Data = added
                };
                progressMessages.Add(nextMessage);
                thread2Messages.Add(nextMessage);
            break;
            case MessageType.Work3:
                var multiplied = message.Data + 1;
                nextMessage = new WorkerStateMessage
                {
                    Type = MessageType.Work4,
                    Progress = "Multiply by 2",
                    Data = multiplied
                };
                progressMessages.Add(nextMessage);
                thread2Messages.Add(nextMessage);
            break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Thread 2

```
private static void Team2Shots()
{
   foreach(var message in thread2Messages.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        WorkerStateMessage nextMessage;
        switch(message.Type)
        {
            case MessageType.Work2:
                var added = message.Data + 2;
                nextMessage = new WorkerStateMessage
                {
                    Type = MessageType.Work3,
                    Progress = "Add 2",
                    Data = added
                };
                progressMessages.Add(nextMessage);
                thread1Messages.Add(nextMessage);
            break;
            case MessageType.Work4:
                var divided = message.Data / 2;
                nextMessage = new WorkerStateMessage 
                {
                    Type = MessageType.Work3,
                    Progress = "Divide by 2",
                    Data = divided
                };
                progressMessages.Add(nextMessage);
                thread2Messages.Add(nextMessage);
            break;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Add 1
Current data: 2
Add 1
Current data: 3
Add 1
Current data: 4
Add 2
Current data: 4
Add 2
Current data: 5
Add 2
Current data: 6
Multiply by 2
Current data: 5
Multiply by 2
Current data: 6
Multiply by 2
Current data: 7
Divide by 2
Current data: 2
Divide by 2
Current data: 3
Divide by 2
Current data: 3
```